# WCF self-hosted WebService AddresFilter mismatch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soapui, self-hosting

I migrate my working self-hosted WebService to HTTPS. I got this error when I try to make a call to a method:

```
  <s:Fault>
     <s:Code>
        <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
        <s:Subcode>
           <s:Value>a:DestinationUnreachable</s:Value>
        </s:Subcode>
     </s:Code>
     <s:Reason>
        <s:Text xml:lang="it-IT">The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.</s:Text>
     </s:Reason>
  </s:Fault>
```

This is my app.Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="XWebServiceLib.XWebService"  behaviorConfiguration="XWebServiceBehave">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://xxx.yyy.it/XWebService"/> 
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="XWebServiceLib.IXWebService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="XWebServiceBehave">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"  httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>                 
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Before migrating to HTTPS everything was working fine... Any idea?

Comment: How is this related to the tool [tag:soapui]?

Answer (score 2):

On my side, it works well. In addition to trusting the server-side’s certificate, we need to add a default `wsa:to` action.
[image]
Namely, below SOAP header is required in the SOAP message.
[image]
Afterward, it works properly. Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Besides, if the previous solution I replied to your question is useful, please mark it as an answer. thanks ^.^